# XPath for elements at multiple levels?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stationary>
    <textbook>
        <name>test</name>
    </textbook>
    <notebook>
        <books>
            <name>test</name>
        </books>
    </notebook>
</stationary>
```

I am trying to get all **`name`** elements irrespective of their position in **`stationary`**

I have tried using the following syntax but it didn't work:

```
stationary/*/name/text()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the following expression with a relative path:

```
//name
```

This seems to capture the two `<name>` tags you have in your XML sample:

```
Element='<name>test</name>'
Element='<name>test</name>'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
'stationary//name/text()'
```

Answer (score 4):

Your XPath,

```
/stationary/*/name/text()
```

will only select the text nodes contained in the `name` element under `textbook` because `/*` selects a *child* element, but the other `name` element is a *grandchild* of `stationary`, not a child of it.

The simplest change would be to replace `/*/` with `//` (as mentioned by 
@GillesQuenot, +1),

```
/stationary//name/text()
```

which will select along the descendant-or-self axis, so it'll select grandchildren, and you'll get both `name` elements' `text()` nodes.

Do note that you say you're trying to get `name` elements, so technically you ought to drop the `text()` step,

```
/stationary//name
```

which will select all `name` element descendants of the `stationary` element.  Then, as a final note, this XPath (as mentioned by @TimBiegeleisen, +1),

```
//name
```

will select all `name` elements in the document regardless of the root element.